# changing object value using reduce in javascript

Tags: javascript, reduce

I wanna change object's value using reduce, but the result is different from what I expect.

```js
const test = [
  {id: 'start', value: false},
  {id: 'reject', value: false},
];

let ress;
const showModal = (which) => {
  const res = test.reduce((res, s) => {
    ress = {id: s.id, value: s.id === which ? (s.value = true) : (s.value = false)};
    return ress;
  }, []);
}

showModal('start');
console.log(ress);
```

Actual result:

```js
{
  "id": "reject",
  "value":false
}
```

Expected:

```js
[
  {id: 'start', value: true},
  {id: 'reject', value: false},
]
```

I don't get it, why `{id:'start', value:true}` is removed and
`key` is changed into `string` type.

Here's working example:
https://codepen.io/seoulsaram/pen/RwpJRPv?editors=1010

Thanks!

Comment: Your reduce function returns `ress`, which is the current element. Therefore the result is the last element. You're abusing reduce anyway it seems; you probably want something like `test.find(modal => modal.id === which).value = true`

Comment: You really what to have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple things to note. In `reduce`, you should return the accumulating array each iteration, but instead you were returning the variable you were creating inside the loop (`res` not `ress`) - they have very similar names so it was an easy typo.

Your ternary condition wasn't correct (it was causing an incorrect response) and could be simplified.
`value: s.id === which ? (s.value = true) : (s.value = false)` doesn't evaluate correctly - much easier to do `value: s.id === which`

Each iteration I used the `[...]` spread operator to concatenate the accumulating array with the new object.

```js
const test = [{
    id: 'start',
    value: false
  },
  {
    id: 'reject',
    value: false
  },
];

let ress;
const showModal = (which) => {
  return test.reduce((res, s) => {
    ress = {
      id: s.id,
      value: s.id === which
    };
    return [...res, ress]
  }, []);
}

console.log(showModal('start'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const res = test.reduce((res, s) => {
  ress = {
    id: s.id,
    value: s.id === which ? (s.value = true) : (s.value = false)
  };
  return ress; // returning always last object as result.
}, []);
```

This code is incorrect, you are pushing always the newest object.

Here how it should look like (it's not the best way to achieve that, I just made your code work as you expect):

```js
const res = test.reduce((res, s) => {
  const ress = {
    id: s.id,
    value: s.id === which ? (s.value = true) : (s.value = false)
  }
  res.push(ress)
  return res; // return accumulator instead of object
}, []);
```

According to your question, is looks like you are looking for [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) not reduce.

This is better approach to your case (mutates orginal array):

```js
const test = [
  {id: 'start', value: false},
  {id: 'reject', value: false},
]

const showModal = (which) => {
  const found = test.find(e => e.id === which)
  found.value = true // it will mutate object in array
}

showModal('start')
console.log(test)
```

Another solution (does not mutate orginal array):

```js
const test = [
  {id: 'start', value: false},
  {id: 'reject', value: false},
]

const showModal = (which) => test.map(e => e.id === which ? ({...e, value: true}) : {...e})

const res = showModal('start')

console.log('res', res)
console.log('test', test)
```

Comment: I like this answer, but I would prefer not to mutate the original test result. ```test``` obj may use in other function later.

Comment: @ikhvjs Yes, I'm not sure what exactly OP wanted, I added immutable aprpoach also.